# Get HTTP Response from a url by using C#

Tags: http, c#-4.0, get, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Environment: ASP.Net MVC 4 using C#

I need to get image by using GET request to a URL `/inbound/faxes/{id}/image`
I used the code below

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("/inbound/faxes/238991717/image");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

System.IO.StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

but it flags "URL not valid"

I used the complete URL `www.interfax.net/inbound/faxes/{id}/image`

but the result is same

I want to follow this article to receive faxes

[Accepting incoming fax notifications by callback](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/rest/dev-guide/2985)

Can anyone help me to get fax...?

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the URL with the protocol (`http://`) and suffixing it with the file extension of the image (`.jpg`, `.png` etc)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] imageData = client.DownloadData("http://www.interfax.net/inbound/faxes/{id}/image");
}
```

Notice how the url is prefixed with the protocol (HTTP in this case). Also make sure you have replaced the `{id}` part of the url with the actual id of the image you are trying to retrieve.